# Java servlet not debugging

Tags: java, spring, servlets, java-ee-6

I had the following problem, there is a servlet written in Java, it has a post method, which I refer to from a JSP file from a form. The method executes fine, but the IDE ignores the breakpoints. I don't understand what could be the problem. Maybe there is some servlet setting that I forgot to put in. And yes, do not write platitudes like compiled files do not match the code and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have the Skip All Breakpoints enabled by mistake.

Or this could be due to issue of any change in source code, due to which Debugger is not able to recognize the breakpoint. In such a situation, click on Remove All Breakpoints, and again place them at and check.